# Remove duplicates from an array of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I remove duplicates from this array?

```
product_areas = [["1", "2", "3"], ["3", "1", "2"]]
```

I have tried `product_areas.uniq!`, `product_area.uniq` but the same thing is repeating. What am I missing here?

**Expected Output:**

```
product_areas = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: what do you want the end result to be? an array of arrays? or a single array? If the end result is just a single array then @newmediafreak's answer is probably what you want

Comment: I want a single array of uniq elements. @newmediafreak's answer is right. But need 4 mins more to mark it as accepted.!

Comment: Do you want `[[1,2,2],[2,1,2]]` => [1,2]` and `[[1,2,2],[2,1,3]]` => [1,2,3]`, or `[[1,2,2],[2,1,2]]` => [1,2,2]` and `[[1,2,2],[2,1,3]] => [[1,2,2],[2,1,3]]`, or something else? Please answer by editing the question, rather than explaining in comments.

Comment: I suggest that in future you hold off awhile before selecting your preferred answer. Doing so discourages other answers and is inconsiderate to others who are still working on their answers. Many SO members wait a couple of hours or more before making a selection. There's no rush, just don't forget.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I agree with you.  Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Your edit does not clarify at all. An example such as `[[1,2,2],[3,1,2I]`, with an expected result of `[1,2,3]` would be better (assuming that's the result you want). You could give that as a second example.

Comment: I understand but i stuck with this example only. So i asked the same thing here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
product_areas = [["1", "2", "3"], ["3", "1", "2"]].flatten.uniq
```

Using `flatten` on your array will create the following result:

```
["1", "2", "3", "3", "1", "2"]
```

When you call `uniq` on that array, you will get the result you were expecting:

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 3):

As previously pointed out

```
product_areas = [["1", "2", "3"], ["3", "1", "2"]].flatten.uniq
```

-OR-

```
product_areas.flatten.uniq!
```

will both lead you to your desired answer.

### Why?

When you were running "product_areas.uniq!" the process was comparing the two inner arrays against each other, other than the elements of each array. Because both `["1", "2", "3"]` and `["3", "1", "2"]` are unique in the array, neither will be removed. As an example say you had the following array

```
product_areas = [["1", "2", "3"], ["3", "1", "2"], ["1","2","3"]]
```

and you ran:

```
product_areas = product_areas.uniq
```

product_areas would then look like the following:

```
product_areas = [["1", "2", "3"], ["3", "1", "2"]]
```

What you need to be aware of when running any sort of enumerable method on arrays is it will only move down to each individual element. So if inside an array you have more arrays, any iterative method will look at the inner array as a whole. Some sample code to demonstrate this:

```
array_of_arrays = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

array_of_arrays.each do |array|
  p array
end
#---OUPUT---
# [1, 2, 3]
# [4, 5, 6]

array_of_arrays.each do |array|
  array.each do |element|
    p element
  end
end
#---OUPUT---
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this little snippet of code over and over again in my career as a Ruby on Rails developer to solve this frequently encountered problem in a single piece of neat little code. The end result of this code is that you can just call something like

```
product_areas.squish
```

to do the following:

1. flatten 2-D arrays into 1-D arrays
2. remove nil elements
3. remove duplicate elements

I do this by adding an initializer `config/initializer/core_ext.rb` to my project which extends the core Ruby functionality as follows:

```
class Array
  def squish
      blank? ? [] : flatten.compact.uniq
  end
end

class NilClass
  def squish
      []
  end
end
```